# Add target without template in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I want to add a build target to my Xcode project without using a template.

None of the target templates really match what I want to do, and I kind of hate templates anyway. What I'm looking for is something like Visual Studio's "Empty Project" option (not the same as an empty project in Xcode, which more closely resembles a blank solution in VS).

I have weeded through what little documentation I could find about targets and I couldn't find any mention of something like this. I am a total Xcode newbie though, so I may well have missed something.

Is there any way to just say "I have these source files, please compile them" without introducing a bunch of cruft that I will need to weed out later?

Comment: what are you going to compile your files into?

Comment: An executable? Is there something else you can compile them into?

Comment: Target is a set of rules how your files get compiled into executable and where to put it once it's done. So how are you going compile it into executable w/o a target?

Comment: I am working on the Mac port of a game. I know I need Cocoa, but I only want to touch it as much as is necessary to set up rendering, input, etc. I don't need nib files or XCTest or any of the other cruft introduced by the "Cocoa Application" template. The "Command Line/Foundation" template seems close to what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the template that includes what you need (Cocoa Application probable) and delete the things you do not need such as XCTest.

The more you fight Objective-C and the "Apple Way" the harder port will be. I initially resisted Objective-C, a high mistake that ultimately code me time.